# str_split() not working properly in PHP when using string with special characters

Tags: php, arrays, special-characters

I am trying out the following

```
$x = "126·10⁴";
$array = str_split($x);
echo "x = " . $x . "<br>";
echo "Array length: " . count($array) . "<br>";

 echo "Charset: " .mb_detect_encoding($x)."<br>";

foreach($array as $i)
    echo $i .  " ";
```

which gives as output:

```
x = 126·10⁴
Array length: 10
Charset: UTF-8
1 2 6 � � 1 0 � � �
```

I want the `·` and `⁴` to be 1 character in the array, how can this be done?
What I am trying to reach is to iterate over all characters of a string, so any other solution is also welcome.

Comment: First comment in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#107658

Comment: Don't post answers in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [comment in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#107658) (Thanks to @Rizier123), the proper way to do this is as following:

```
function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
    if ($l > 0) {
        $ret = array();
        $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
            $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

Comment: This function helps me in my `base64_decode` string. Thanks for this answer!!